# Data view scroll issue sencha touch

Tags: javascript, css, sencha-touch, extjs, dataview

**Hi**, I am using **sencha touch 1.X** and I am having issues on different types of mobile devices with my dataviews.

The problem is that my **panel containing my dataview** does **not scale** to the dataview's size.

Here is the code :

```
AppCenter.views.HomeList = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    scroll: 'vertical',
    items : [{
        scroll: false,  
        id: 'list-data-view',
        xtype: 'dataview',
        store: AppCenter.stores.ListStore,
        itemSelector:'div .category-container',
        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate
        (
            my tpl
        )
    }]
});
```

On recent mobile it works fine. But when trying on iPhone 3G and below it does the following.

The scroller has the size of my window whereas my dataview is much bigger than the window.

**Any tips ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the iPhone screen resolution. Maybe the problem is in your template or some custom css. Do you use somewhere absolute pixels?

Comment: i will try on a new project with only big dataview in panel and tell you the result.

Comment: Apparently it was the float elements that were not working under 3gs. Manage to fix it

Comment: Additionnaly the setHeight on my caroussel is not working 3GS and below. It mess up the layout.So weird...